# PDO Select statement returns false even row exists

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im writing a script to add a big list of products to my database.
It searches for category of a product in categories table and if it exists it takes id of that category and so on.
But my pdo select statement never returns a value and it adds hundreds of same categories..
My pdo statement is:

```
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name = '".$fields[2]."' ")->fetch();
        if ( $query ){
               //Do something
                     }
```

$fields[2] variable %90 of the time returns a value that exists in the table but every single time this query returns false..

**Update**
Changed query to;

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name = ? ');
    $stmt->execute([$fields[2]]);
    $query = $stmt->fetch();
    if ( $query ){
//bla bla
     }
```

Still adds every value as new category

Comment: this is vulnerable to SQL injection. Learn how to write your queries properly and securely. It may also, depending on the exact issue you're experiencing, fix your lack of results. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: was using query variable as {$fields[2]} but im trying every possible way.. and im getting values from my excel file so there is no risk of sql injection in this script ty for info btw :) @ADyson

Comment: Well that depends where the Excel data originated, don't you think? And there might also still be a risk of accidental sql syntax errors too due to unescaped characters in the input. Using parameterised queries is just good practice...there is never an excuse not to. Just have a rule that you don't trust any input, no matter where it came from. That way there can be no surprises. Fix that, and see if you still have a problem afterwards

Comment: @ADyson i updated the code and its still working same..

Comment: Only real conclusion from that is that $fields[2] doesn't match anything on the database. That could be due to strange hidden characters in either the input or database data, or encoding mismatches, or you're connecting to the wrong copy of the database, or your debugging is inaccurate about the contents of $fields[2] when the query is executed. We're blind to all the data and to any of the config so it's hard to be sure. You need to rule out possible causes one by one.

Comment: Alternatively there's a small chance the query is crashing for a different reason but that should result in some sort of error or warning in PHP. So unless you are suppressing those or not looking for them in the right place we can probably rule that out...but just wanted to mention it, as that kind of oversight does happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM categories WHERE name=:f_name');
$stmt->execute(['f_name' => $fields[2]]);
$query = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if ( $query ){
}
```

Comment: value of $fields[2] come from input? did you checks $fields[2] is null or not before query?

Comment: its not null it prints out when i type print $fields[2]; and it prints correct values

Comment: did you check the query with some real value without using that variable?

Comment: $query = $stmt->fetchColumn(); use this . this is for select only single field.

Comment: real value works not fetchcolumn(); function

Comment: if type of $fields[2]  is not string. $name = (string)$fields[2]; and pass $name.